# Angular 5 - How to set null as content type for HTTP POST multipart/form-data

Tags: angular

How to set null as content type for HTTP POST multipart/form-data

below is code which is not working :

```
let abc = new FormData();
abc.append('name', "dgdhghdhd");
abc.append('file', this.doc); //doc is a file object
abc.append('product_image', "ssss");

console.log("form data  ---->")
console.log(abc)
this.http.post('http://localhost:8080/create_product', abc, {
  headers: new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', '')
})
  .subscribe(data => {
    console.log(data)

  });
```

this is not working i can see content type is setting as text/html bydefault.

Comment: Do you set the Content Type to "text/html" somewhere else? Because that's not a default value as far as I know...

Comment: Also, why do you want it set to null and not multipart/form-data anyway?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to set any Content-Type and it works. If the content type gets changed you probably do also something else. Here is the code I have used:

```
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular 6';
  content = null;
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    const formData: FormData = new FormData();
    formData.append('test', 'test');
    http.post('https://httpbin.org/post', formData).subscribe((next) => this.content = next);
  }
}
```

I have posted a working sample on [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/formdatapost?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) that posts to https://httpbin.org that mirrors back the request and you can see it is posted correctly. It uses Angular 6 but I don't think this has changed from version 5. The new HttpClient came with version 4.